# Grease Pencil partially rendering on Eevee, with some lines disappearing with 'edge marks'

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, grease-pencil, lineart

Good day!
I am currently having problems when trying to render the grease pencil.
I made a model that only uses the option "Edge Marks" in the Line Art modifier.
In the viewport, everything looks right, but when I try to render in Eevee, some of the lines disappear.
My version is Blender 3.4

[image: This is in the viewport]

[image: This is what happens when I render]

What can I do to solve this problem?
Have a great day!